# Может ли бот написать определенному пользователю если он знает его id?

Tags: python, telegram, бот, aiogram

Сразу скажу бот не используется в группах, только используется в ЛС (Клиент и бот, все). У меня цель такая. Когда клиент общается с ботом, бот выдает ему список товаров, когда клиент выбрал товар, бот собирает данные товара и данные клиента (клиент ввел их заранее) и отправляет определённому пользователю (Директору и только ему). Все это должно происходить автоматически без вмешательства человека. Если вы сможете мне помочь с написанием кода, очень буду благодарен!

Если нужны уточнения, спрашивайте

То есть схема такова (слева на право): Клиент - Бот - Директор.

Пожалуйста помогите, уточняйте если это по вашему мнению не обходимо.

Comment: бот как минимум должен быть в контактах директора, тогда все должно получиться, бот не может быть инициатором общения, в крайнем случае директору и боту нужно будет иметь общую приватную группу

Comment: Да я знаю что боты не могут быть первыми инициаторами общения но почему он должен быть в контактах то? Вы можете написать хендлер который отправляет нужному пользователю информацию?

Comment: Потому что инициатор общения будет директор который добавит к себе бота и нажмет кнопку старт - в этом и есть смысл начала общения. Если бы было так как Вы полагаете то в телеграмм не возможно было бы зайти, боты бы атаковали на право и налево)) А так - добавил бота то значит разрешил ему писать тебе

Comment: Да это я понял, что бот не может написать первым, у меня проблема с функцией которая выполняет это действие. Мне уже отвечали ответом что у send_message есть chat_id  в который нужно засунуть нужный мне id. Но как это реализовать я не понимаю, в будущем постараюсь по подробнее изучить библиотеку aiogram, а пока что я как угорелый петух пытаюсь найти решение

Comment: Клиент выбирает товар у бота, после бот берет данные клиента и товар который он выбрал и это он должен отдать Директору и это все должно проходить автоматически, с ботом и клиентом у меня проблем нет, но вот чтоб бот написал сам Директору (чат уже открыт между Директором и Ботом) вот с эти у меня страшные проблемы, если я смогу это реализовать то 1\3 ТЗ у же сделанна

Comment: вот [пример](https://surik00.gitbooks.io/aiogram-lessons/content/chapter1.html) эхобота он может потом через какое-то время сам слать сообщения зная id (ведь нет никаких ограничений когда он должен дать ответ и сколько раз) насчет списка товара уж сами решайте как Вы будете его забирать у клиента. как только список будет готов `await bot.send_message(id_director, list_products)` list_products - разумеется должен быть строкой но ее можно оформить по разному например с переводом строки

Comment: то есть мне нужно просто написать так? bot.send_message(1234567890, list_products)

Comment: Так что то я не понимаю, не может быть все так просто

Comment: да именно так и этого хватит), но про контакты я выше писал

Comment: при нормальном использовании библиотек и ботов не должно быть сложно)

Comment: спасибо, вы мне помогли  гору с плеч убрать, я думал что завалю свой первый заказ просто застряв на этом пункте.